# Summarizing all rows that link to a column

Tags: r, dplyr

For my assignment I have a dataset consisting of Olympic participants. I need to summarize the mean BMI for each Olympic Sport. I created the BMI column up front and have the following code:

```
olympics <- mutate(olympics, BMI = (Weight/(Height*Height)*10000))
answer6 <- olympics %>% 
            group_by(Sport, BMI, Sport) %>% 
            summarise()
```

This leaves me with a table with 13.000 rows. This needs to be a summarized table with 1 row for each sport, and then the average BMI for that sport.

After that I need to store the top5 mean bmi's of those countries in a new object in decreasing order. The end result will look like this:

Sport   Mean_BMI
Sport1  19.5
Sport2  19.2
Sport3  19.1
Sport4  18.6
Sport5  18.1

my data looks like:

```
structure(list(Name = c("A Lamusi", "Juhamatti Tapio Aaltonen", 
"Andreea Aanei", "Jamale (Djamel-) Aarrass (Ahrass-)", "Nstor Abad Sanjun", 
"Nstor Abad Sanjun"), Sex = c("M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M"), 
    Age = c(23L, 28L, 22L, 30L, 23L, 23L), Height = c(170L, 184L, 
    170L, 187L, 167L, 167L), Weight = c(60, 85, 125, 76, 64, 
    64), Team = c("China", "Finland", "Romania", "France", "Spain", 
    "Spain"), NOC = c("CHN", "FIN", "ROU", "FRA", "ESP", "ESP"
    ), Games = c("2012 Summer", "2014 Winter", "2016 Summer", 
    "2012 Summer", "2016 Summer", "2016 Summer"), Year = c(2012L, 
    2014L, 2016L, 2012L, 2016L, 2016L), Season = c("Summer", 
    "Winter", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer"), City = c("London", 
    "Sochi", "Rio de Janeiro", "London", "Rio de Janeiro", "Rio de Janeiro"
    ), Sport = c("Judo", "Ice Hockey", "Weightlifting", "Athletics", 
    "Gymnastics", "Gymnastics"), Event = c("Judo Men's Extra-Lightweight", 
    "Ice Hockey Men's Ice Hockey", "Weightlifting Women's Super-Heavyweight", 
    "Athletics Men's 1,500 metres", "Gymnastics Men's Individual All-Around", 
    "Gymnastics Men's Floor Exercise"), Medal = c(NA, "Bronze", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), BMI = c(20.7612456747405, 25.1063327032136, 
    43.2525951557093, 21.7335354170837, 22.9481157445588, 22.9481157445588
    ), weightcategories = structure(c(3L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 4L
    ), .Label = c("31-40", "41-50", "51-60", "61-70", "71-80", 
    "81-90", "91-100", "101-110", "111-120", "121-130", "131-140", 
    "141-150", "151-160"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", 
"Sex", "Age", "Height", "Weight", "Team", "NOC", "Games", "Year", 
"Season", "City", "Sport", "Event", "Medal", "BMI", "weightcategories"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the `BMI` column , you need to `group_by` only by `Sport` take the `mean` and select top 5 mean values and `arrange` them in descending order.

```
library(dplyr)

olympics %>% 
   group_by(Sport) %>% 
   summarise(mean = mean(BMI)) %>%
   top_n(5,mean) %>%
   arrange(desc(mean))
```

---

In base R that would be

```
df1 <- aggregate(BMI~Sport, olympics, mean)
df1[order(df1$BMI, decreasing = TRUE)[1:5], ]
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment. How would you translate this into base R code?

I'd figure it has something to do with the aggregate function, something like:

```
setNames(aggregate(Sport, 
                               aggregate(Sport ~ mean(BMI), 
                     c("Sport", "Mean_BMI"))))
```

Comment: @TvanCasteren yes, updated with the base R version.